# Setup firebase - Unity project - com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity & MessageForwardingService Not found

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am setting up firebase base project for Push notification , and my main activity extends **UnityPlayerActivity**.
From doc : [enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client)

If your custom activity extends UnityPlayerActivity you can instead extend **com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity** , but not able to find this anywhere and  MessageForwardingService also

And not getting notification is application extends  **UnityPlayerActivity**

Comment: are you extending UnityPlayerActivity instead of using the SDK for some reason?

Comment: Yes, i need to do so task  from native code only

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - The class you need to extend doesn't appear anywhere in the project, but I think it gets added at build-time under the `com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity` path.

So, you can reference it by always using the full path like so:

```
package your.package;


import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity;

public class YourClass extends com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Do whatever you want
        
        // Call parent onCreate
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```